# KMP prefix construction with NASM

Tags: c, linux, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to implement the following C code in NASM and then link it to a C program&run from there.

The code I'm trying to implement:

```
   void preKmp(char *x, int m, int kmpNext[]) {
   int i, j;

   i = 0;
   j = kmpNext[0] = -1;
   while (i < m) {
      while (j > -1 && x[i] != x[j])
         j = kmpNext[j];
      i++;
      j++;
      if (x[i] == x[j])
         kmpNext[i] = kmpNext[j];
      else
         kmpNext[i] = j;
   }
}
```

My attempt in NASM with my comments:

```
;nasm -f elf32 table.asm -o table.o

segment .bss
kmpNext resd 256


segment .text
global table

table:
    push ebp          ;save the old base pointer value
    mov  ebp,esp      ;base pointer <- stack pointer

    mov eax,[ebp+8]     ;function argument, eax = search_string
    mov ecx, 0          ;i = 0
    mov edx, -1         ;j = -1
    mov [kmpNext], edx  ;kmpNext[0] = -1
oWhile:
    cmp byte [eax + ecx*4], 0  ;end of array control
    je finished
iWhile:
    cmp edx, -1
    jle pass
    mov edi,[eax + ecx*4] ;edi = x[i]
    mov esi,[eax + edx*4] ;esi = x[j]
    cmp edi, esi
    je pass
    mov edx, [kmpNext +edx*4] ;j = kmpNext[j]
pass:
    inc ecx
    inc edx
    mov edi,[eax + ecx*4] ;edi = x[i]
    mov esi,[eax + edx*4] ;esi = x[j]
    cmp edi, esi
    jne store
    mov edi, [kmpNext + edx*4]  ;edi = kmpNext[j]
    mov [kmpNext + ecx*4], edi  ;kmpNext[i] = edi
store:
    mov [kmpNext + ecx*4], edx  ;kmpNext[i] = j
    jmp oWhile
finished:
    mov eax, kmpNext;

    pop ebp
    ret
```

My C code in which I call the NASM function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int* table(char *str);

int main(void)
{
    char str[256];
    int i, n, *pre;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s" , str) ;
    n = strlen(str);
    pre = table(str);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
      printf("%d ", pre[i]);

    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Everything compiles and run OK but the output is wrong. For example,

for 'cocacola' I should get: -1 -1 0 -1 0 1 -1 -1

where I get: -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Can someone point out my mistake in the NASM code ?

I suspect that the problem is with this line:

mov esi, [eax + ecx*4]

When I run a debugger, I don't see a change in contents of esi.

Comment: So why do you think every one knows what "KMP" means and you do not need to provide a clear description? Use a debugger.

Comment: It's irrevelant and everyone has google. I'm just trying to implement the function I provided on the top.

Comment: It is **you** seeking help and it is a rule of this site. Otherwise you should use google to find an answer to your question! "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."

Comment: Everything is clear in my question. Stop whining. Provide an answer if you want to be helpful to other users. I'm just inexperienced with debugging an assembly. This is the reason why I can't be more precise.

Comment: With that attitude you better try on Facebook. People here help voluntarily. EOM

Comment: I'm not arguing or anything. What's lacking in my question ? Please do tell me and I'll do my best to patch it up.

Comment: Your C-function gives me for 'cocacola': -1 0 -1 1 -1 0 2 0. My implementation of the original KMP gives -1 0 0 1 0 1 2 0. What's going on?

Comment: Ok that might be wrong too.

Comment: In the NASM code I don't see the jumps back to `oWhile` and `iWhile`. So the while loops are computed only one time.

Comment: I noticed and fixed that but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The main error is, that `str` is an array of bytes (8 bits), but you treat it as an array of integers (32 bits).

2) There are two while loops. **Both** of them need a jump-back for repetition.

3) `store` is the `else`-case. It must not run, if the the `if`-case fits. In this case is appropriate a jump to `oWhile`.

This is the corrected function:

```
table:
    push ebp          ;save the old base pointer value
    mov  ebp,esp      ;base pointer <- stack pointer

    push edi          ; callee saved
    push ebx

    mov eax,[ebp+8]     ;function argument, eax = search_string
    mov ecx, 0          ;i = 0
    mov edx, -1         ;j = -1
    mov [kmpNext], edx  ;kmpNext[0] = -1

oWhile:
    cmp byte [eax + ecx], 0  ;end of array control
    je finished

iWhile:
    cmp edx, -1
    jle pass

    mov bl,[eax + ecx] ; bl = x[i]
    mov bh,[eax + edx] ; bh = x[j]
    cmp bl, bh

    je pass
    mov edx, [kmpNext +edx*4] ;j = kmpNext[j]
    jmp iWhile

pass:
    inc ecx
    inc edx

    mov bl,[eax + ecx] ; bl = x[i]
    mov bh,[eax + edx] ; bh = x[j]
    cmp bl, bh

    jne store
    mov edi, [kmpNext + edx*4]  ;edi = kmpNext[j]
    mov [kmpNext + ecx*4], edi  ;kmpNext[i] = edi

    jmp oWhile

store:
    mov [kmpNext + ecx*4], edx  ;kmpNext[i] = j
    jmp oWhile

finished:
    mov eax, kmpNext;

    pop ebx
    pop edi
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Still missing some parts I think. For example, aaaa should return -1,0,1,2 rite ?

Comment: @SpiderRico: It does what the C-function does. I'm still convinced that your algorithm is wrong. But that was not the question.

Comment: Ah you're rite! The original algorithm I posted is wrong. I'll work from your code anyway. Thanks

Comment: Or perhaps just a different imp. It's from there ->  http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node8.html

Comment: @SpiderRico: It seems that there are different algrithms that produce different tables. My personal implementation of [this algorithm](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt-Algorithmus#Pr.C3.A4fix-Analyse_2) produces indeed -1,0,1,2 .

Answer (score 1):

```
oWhile:
    cmp byte [eax + ecx*4], 0
```

This is not equivalent to `while (i < m)`. It should be:

```
oWhile:
    cmp ecx,[ebp+12]
    jge finished
```

You should not `mov eax, [kmpNext]` before return; it is a void function (though no harm - the compiler will ignore the return value).

Also, you may need to save `edi` and `esi` and possibly other registers as otherwise the caller can get confused. Check your C compiler's manual about it.

Comment: That didn't fix it. Problem seems to be related with comparison.

Comment: What exactly does eax contains in my code ? Is it a reference to the string I supplied ? Error seems to be related with it.

Comment: Check `cmp bl, bh': why load/compare the `l` part of the register if `kmpNext` are integers? You should load the full register. Your question: `eax` contains a pointer. You use it corectly.